# How to save settings for each user on the site?

Tags: django

I have a site based on django. And it shows some graphs. Graphs have several settings. I need each user to be able to change these settings for themselves.
How is this possible?
And another question, is it possible for these parameters to be saved the next time for each user?

Comment: Having a user field in a model implies that one cannot access objects they didn't create, and they cannot edit items they didn't create themselves. This restriction only applies when the model lacks a user field.